# Tracing the emission of a symbol

Tags: debugging, rust, compilation, linker, embedded

I’m debugging some embedded code that must not panic through the "panic_never" crate. Still, the rust_begin_unwind symbol is emitted somewhere and can’t find its origin. Is there any tool or method to understand what triggers the emission of a given symbol in object files (before linking) ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any tool or method to understand what triggers the emission of a given symbol in object files

Step 1: find the object which references the symbol. You could add the linker `rustc -C link-args=-Wl,-y,rust_begin_unwind`, which should print all objects which reference the symbol, or by running `nm -A *.o | grep rust_begin_unwind`.

Step 2: find out why a given object has the reference: compile the source which produced this problematic `.o` to assembly ([instructions](https://medium.com/journey-to-rust/viewing-assembly-for-rust-function-d4870baad941)). Assembly should give you an idea of *why* `rust_begin_unwind` is being called.

Comment: Interesting. The linker error gave me the reference to the object file. I disassembled it / decompiled it using Cutter (https://github.com/rizinorg/cutter) but the code was comprised of a few unusual load instruction I couldn't trace to my original code. No references or jumps to `rust_begin_unwind` were found in any other symbols of the object file. Maybe there could be a compiler flag to trace the emission of the symbol ? Or maybe a way to selectively dump the AST / MIR / IR at the right place which could help me trace the origin of the function ?

Comment: @Magix I know very little about Rust. I suggest trying to create an MCVE and asking a new question along the lines of "What causes `rustc` to emit a reference to ... given this source?"